Uniform Probability, Intuitive $X > Y$
Let's say $X$ is uniformly distributed from $0.3$ to $0.9$, and $Y$ is uniformly distributed from $0.6$ to $0.8$. Both IID. Is there any intuitive/geometric way of determining $P(X>Y)$? I know how to calculate by splitting up $X$ into $[0.3,0.6]$, and $[0.8,0.9]$, but am not sure if there's a better way of doing this.

Hint: graph the sets and think about area.

That's exactly what I'm looking for, but am unsure how to graph the sets. Could you hint me?

No way to find $P(X>Y)$ unless $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Note that IID stands for "Independent and Identically Distributed." It does not make sense to say "both IID" when they do not have the same distributions. You mean to say "$X$ and $Y$ are independent."  To graph it, you want to plot the rectangle $[.3, .9]\times [.6, .8]$ in the $x/y$ plane and also plot how the line $y=x$ cuts that rectangle.
